# How do I get the circles to appear on the pygame screen

Tags: python, pygame, geometry

Below is a small piece of my program. Currently, the program takes the user's input and converts it into a binary number in the Python Shell. I am trying to use that input so that I can graphically display the binary number. At the moment, I am unable to get anything to appear in the pygame screen. It is just white, no circles, no text. I am not sure why it is not working. I was advised by my teacher to turn this piece of code into a procedure, see if I have any luck, then get back to him. I was hoping somebody could pick out what is wrong with my procedure and either point it out to me or correct it. Any help would be much appreciated. I apologize if my formatting for the question is not spectacular, this is my first post.

---

```
from pygame import*

font.init()  
comicFont=font.SysFont("ComicSansMS",12)
screen = display.set_mode((500,500))
binaryWord = str(100101)
binaryDigits = len(binaryWord)
binaryBlit = range(0,10)
binaryGraphicX = 0  
color = (0,0,0)
color2 = (125,125,125)
pos = (binaryGraphicX,200)
radius = 15
width = 0
while True:
    for binaryDigit in range (0,binaryDigits):
        TxtPic = []
        binaryGraphicX = binaryGraphicX + 25        
        if binaryWord[binaryDigit] == 1:
            running=True
            while running:
                for evnt in event.get():
                    if evnt.type==QUIT:
                        running = False
                event.get()
                draw.circle(screen,color,pos,radius)
                display.flip()
                TxtPic[binaryDigit]=comicFont.render(str(2**binaryBlit),True,(0,0,0))
                screen.blit(TxtPic[binaryDigit],(binaryGraphicX,220))
        elif binaryWord[binaryDigit] == 0:
            running=True
            while running:
                for evnt in event.get():
                    if evnt.type==QUIT:
                        running = False
                event.get()
            draw.circle(screen,color2,pos,radius)
            display.flip()
            TxtPic[binaryDigit]=comicFont.render(str(2**binaryBlit),True,(0,0,0))
            screen.blit(TxtPic[binaryDigit],(binaryGraphicX,220))
quit()
```

---

### Below is where I call on the procedure

```
    running=True
    while running:
        for evnt in event.get():
            if evnt.type==QUIT:
                running = False
        event.get()

        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        TxtPic1=comicFont.render(str(solution),True,(255,255,255))
        screen.blit(TxtPic1,(200,200))
        binaryGraphics(binaryNumber)
        display.flip()
    display.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking through your code and the first obvious problem I found was that you are comparing a character/string to an int in your if statements.

ie.

String:

```
binaryWord = str(100101)
```

String to Int comparison: (would return false and skip)

```
if binaryWord[binaryDigit] == 1:
```

Try this instead:

```
if binaryWord[binaryDigit] == "1":
```

Your program never has a chance to get to your code that draws text/circles.

Comment: Also you receive errors with str(2**binaryBlit) , should be str(2*binaryBlit). You will also receive errors assigning to TxtPic[binaryDigit] as your list was initialised blank and so the list index you reference does not exist.